# Confirmation Email Not working Pie Register plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Confirmation email not working, I everyday got many fake subscriber.
why email confirmation email not working ?

"Thank you for your registration" my demo here : evasoft.in

**There are any problem with wordpress ? send mail to user off/on ?**

**Check the screenshot it's my settings in pie registration.**[image]

**Another** 
[image]

Comment: mate nothing looks wrong to me, but speaking about general php function to verify. First the user signs up (i am sure you get that part), Then a mail function is called (that is a easy to use php function) then in that mail there should be a URL with GET data (GET data is after a ? in the URL so for example somesite.com/verify?1233445) Now your back end Should search for the activation token (and user id if the activation token is not a unique) and activate the account.

So in conclusion If you want a job done right, code it your self

Comment: any tutorial available ? there are any problem with my wordpress version i uses latest wp version

Comment: Why don't you try other plugin like [Register Plus Redux](https://wordpress.org/plugins/register-plus-redux/) if are not getting any solution.Or [Click here](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/20-wordpress-plugins-for-improved-user-login-and-registration/) for more list.

Comment: does Register Plus Redux works on frontend register ?

Comment: i just installed Register Plus Redux but still user register it self directly

Comment: no problems with wordpress i just personally don't like using it. if you need a tutorial just browse google for a php social network site there is a few of them and they have great info that could help you